# Change the way request parameters are interpreted

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I use Requests to do some requests to an api.
I want to pass multiple value to a request parameter so I use a list like this:

```
params = {'test_key': [value1, value2]}
requests.get('example.com', params = params)
```

The problem is that the module converts that into "example.com?test_key=value1&test_key=value2".
The api I use do not accept this format but wants something like "example.com?test_key=value1,value2"

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Anything wrong with `','.join([value1, value2])`?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark  That worked thank's!

Comment: No problem, I'll write a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section, using `','.join([value1, value2])` produces the desired string.